# Constructor undefined in a BroadCastReceiver class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to insert data from my remote server into my local database when a gcm message is received from my servers.
I have created a database controller class and broadcastreceiver class.

Database Controller class

```
public class DBController  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "user.db", null, 1);
    }
    //Creates Table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE users ( userId INTEGER, userName TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts User into SQLite DB
     * @param queryValues
     */
    public void insertUser(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("userId", queryValues.get("userId"));
        values.put("userName", queryValues.get("userName"));
        database.insert("users", null, values);
        database.close();
    }

    /**
     * Get list of Users from SQLite DB as Array List
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllUsers() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;
        usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM users";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("userId", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("userName", cursor.getString(1));
                usersList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        database.close();
        return usersList;
    }

}
```

GCMBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    HashMap<String, String> queryValues; 

     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             ...
        }
}
```

Now the problem is when my Database Controller class (DBController.java) is called in the GCMBroadcastReceiver.java class it gives an error message below. Please is there something i am doing wrong?

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The constructor DBController(GCMBroadcastReceiver) is undefined GCMBroadcastReceiver.java   /GCMtest/src/com/gcm/gcmtest    line 14 Java Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your DBController in onReceive() method because the context will be passed to it and you can nuse that context to initialize your DBController.

For ex. like this..

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
DBController controller ;
HashMap<String, String> queryValues; 

 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         controller =new DBController(context);
    }
```

}

I hope this would help you.

Once it is initialized you can use its instance anywhere in this class.

Answer (score 0):

In `GCMBroadcastReceiver`, you have a line with `new DBController(this)` in it. A `BroadcastReceiver` is not a `Context`, and so there is no valid constructor. Use the `Context` passed into `onReceive()`. This will mean delaying initializing that field until `onReceive()`.

Comment: Please do you mean something like this  `public void  onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   DBController controller = new DBController(context);
     }`

Comment: @NewBIe: at least the `controller = new DBController(context);` part. Your choice of whether `DBController controller` is a local variable inside of `onReceive()` or is a field of your class is up to you. Usually, a `BroadcastReceiver` is very short, and so a local variable is usually sufficient. Besides, you should not be doing database I/O from `onReceive()` anyway, as `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your GCMBroadcastReceiver class, you initialize `DBController(this)`. Try initializing your DBController inside of your `onReceive()` method. You can use the context from the method parameter so it looks like this:  `controller = new DBController(context);`

Comment: In this case how can controller be accessed in a different method within the same class?